# Raw mouse and keyboard input for macOS games post-Catalina?

Tags: macos, cocoa, input, game-engine

I have a feeling I know the answer to this question, but it's been surprisingly difficult to confirm it anywhere.  Is it possible to get raw keyboard and mouse input post-Catalina without needing "Input Monitoring" access in the Security & Privacy preferences?

[image: Security & Privacy prompt]

I've never programmed a game engine before on macOS, but so far as I can tell, the "usual" way for games to get raw mouse deltas and raw keyboard states has been to use IOKit's HID API.  Up until [recently](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/616/), this apparently was also the only way to get input from Xbox and Playstation gamepads.

When I attempt to use the IOKit HID API to get mouse and keyboard input, I receive a prompt to allow Input Monitoring in Security & Privacy preferences.  Elsewhere on the internet, I've learned that this is due to a change in macOS Catalina: to use IOKit HID input handling, you now need the Input Monitoring permission.  As far as I'm concerned, it's a deal-breaker for my game to require users turn this on.

Am I understanding this situation correctly?  And if I am, is it just not possible to get raw (unprocessed) keyboard and mouse input without the Input Monitoring permission?  I mean, I can hack together a solution for FPS-style mouse input using [mouseMoved:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1525114-mousemoved) events and the like, but such a solution would disallow sub-pixel precision and would subject my game to macOS's cursor acceleration.  Is there another solution that games/game engines use?

Comment: I've decided to move on with regular Cocoa keyboard events, though this leaves me without a way to detect a few things (like the release of the Caps Lock key).  I still have a little trouble believing that Apple wouldn't have a "preferred" way to get raw mouse deltas suitable for 3D computer games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re willing to take on the macOS 11 requirement, it seems like Apple added raw keyboard and mouse support to the Game Controller framework. Seems to even support caps lock.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gckeyboardinput?language=objc

Comment: Dude, thanks.  This appears to be the "right" answer (at least, according to Apple) that I was looking for.  It sucks about the macOS 11 requirement, though.  I guess I'll have to begrudgingly update, then try this out.